# How do I a rescan all registries with xray?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

Given the recent log4j CVE I would like to re scan all previously scanned components with xray. Is that possible at all? "Scan now" and the equivalent API endpoints don't seem to scan previously scanned components.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the history scan option to perform a rescan of all the Existing Content. This is done by clicking the 'Apply on Existing Content' button in each Xray’s Watch.

Here is a KB article [*xray-updating-an-xray-watch-with-history-scan*](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/xray-updating-an-xray-watch-with-history-scan/) provides more information.